# transition from git to TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have git and I am using it for several projects but I'd like to benefit from tortoisegit interface simplicity. Is there a simple way to install tortoisegit? Do I have to uninstall git first? Do you have any tutorial to have a smooth transition from git only to tortoisegit without losing all the previous versions of projects, the logs and so on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can simply go to TortoiseGit homepage and read installation notes and other links...

Comment: Please also consider [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/): TortoiseGit strives to behave as TortoiseSvn too much, but Subversion is not Git and this dissonanse might cause problems. For an illustration see "Disaster 2" [here](http://randyfay.com/node/89).  Git Extensions, on the other hand, does not try to hide form the user the fact they work with Git.  (No, I'm not affiliated with this piece of software in any way).

Comment: You still need to install the command line git. TortoiseGit calls git.

Answer (score 4):

TortoiseGit is basically just a GUI for Git. You should still be able to use Git as normal, and it won't affect your revision history. The only difference will be that you can interact with the Git repository using TortoiseGit as an alternative to using the command line, so losing project history is not an issue.

Git is actually a prerequisite of TortoiseGit, so it's designed to work with your existing Git install. There are plenty of other interfaces as well - most programmer's text editors and IDE's can integrate with Git if you wish.

You should just be able to install TortoiseGit in the usual way (see https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#install for details), and as long as you have the dependencies installed, it should all work fine.